# The jQuery Validate Plugin *just isn't working*?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

What's wrong with my code?

It's just is not working, and I don't know why!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var userName    = "",
        userEmail   = "",
        roomPass    = "",
        betaCode    = "",
        roomNumber  = "";

    alert("Test!");
    $("#box_create_room").validate({
        submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!"); },
        onfocusout: true,
        rules: {
            box_create_user: {
                required:true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            box_create_email: "required",
            box_create_pass: {
                required:true,
                minlength: 4
            }
        },
        messages: {
            box_create_user: {
                required: "Please enter your name.",
                minlength: "Please enter a name of at least 2 characters."
            },
            box_create_email: "Please enter a valid email",
            box_create_pass: {
                required: "A password for the conference room is required.",
                minlength: "The password must be at least 4 digits."
            }
        }
    });

    /*function createRoom() {

        userName = $("#box_create_user").val();
        userEmail = $("#box_create_email").val();
        roomPin = $("#box_create_pass").val();
    }*/
});
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<form id="box_create_room" method="get" action="">
                <hr class="line" /><hr class="line_emboss" />
                <input type="text" class="box_element" id="box_create_user" name="box_create_user" placeholder="What's your name?" />
                <hr class="line" /><hr class="line_emboss" />
                <input type="email" class="box_element" id="box_create_email" name="box_create_email" placeholder="What's your email?" />
                <hr class="line" /><hr class="line_emboss" />
                <input type="password" class="box_element" id="box_create_pass" name="box_create_pass" placeholder="Choose a Room Pin (4-8 numbers)" maxlength="8" />
                <hr class="line" /><hr class="line_emboss" />
                <input type="submit" class="box_element" id="box_create_submit" value="Create Room" />
            </form>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is a community-driven site where participants answer the questions they like. No one is obliged to do something for you. Please, remove the "Urgent" notice from the title.

Comment: Please remove "{URGENT}" in title topic.

Comment: check firebug to see if there are any javascript errors first.

Comment: Looks like it's "straight-up working" to me: http://jsfiddle.net/xxEg9/

Comment: Well, I solved the issue on my own. Odd browser incompatibility. I apologize for the {Urgent} in the headline, but this is for something that has to go live in a few hours and it's well... extremely urgent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because you're missing the `js` extension on your reference to jQuery validate:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Works fine as posted: http://jsfiddle.net/xxEg9/

**Edit:** *However*, I think specifying `onfocusout: true` is causing a JavaScript error. Specifying `true` for this setting is superfluous anyway, just remove it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var userName    = "",
        userEmail   = "",
        roomPass    = "",
        betaCode    = "",
        roomNumber  = "";

    $("#box_create_room").validate({
        submitHandler: function() { alert("Submitted!"); },
        rules: {
            box_create_user: {
                required:true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            box_create_email: "required",
            box_create_pass: {
                required:true,
                minlength: 4
            }
        },
        messages: {
            box_create_user: {
                required: "Please enter your name.",
                minlength: "Please enter a name of at least 2 characters."
            },
            box_create_email: "Please enter a valid email",
            box_create_pass: {
                required: "A password for the conference room is required.",
                minlength: "The password must be at least 4 digits."
            }
        }
    });

    /*function createRoom() {

        userName = $("#box_create_user").val();
        userEmail = $("#box_create_email").val();
        roomPin = $("#box_create_pass").val();
    }*/
});
```

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/J8J7L/

Comment: You copied everything correctly except the .js?  How is that possible?

Comment: @Nick: Even so, does the script get loaded successfully? If you replace your reference with a CDN does it work? Try http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js instead of your local version.

Comment: @Jack Because I copied each script tag separately and manually typed most of that tag.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I tried with a CDN also. I just won't work. And I can't get it to work on the posted one either. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Nick: IE9 (and 7/8 compatibility mode), Chrome, FF 5.0

Comment: I couldn't get it to work in Chrome at all, I searched for issues with the plugin in Chrome, apparently it has something to do with HTML5 validation overriding the plugin. I added a line at the bottom of the page and it fixed it. A completely stupid issue and a rookie mistake.

Comment: @Nick: I did see some JS errors pop up and I believe I found the cause. See if the updated example works for you.

Comment: Yes, I removed the onfocusout. I had only added it to try to brute force it into working. I included another file from the plugin I downloaded and it suddenly started working. It's odd because there's no way to get that file through the CDN.

Comment: @Nick: What file is that? I'm still not seeing a problem in Chrome.

Comment: `jquery.delegate.js` I included it and the errors stopped. And I stuck `$('form').attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');` at the bottom of the page, but overrides HTML5 validation. I know that's an issue in Chrome 11+, but I have a development build of 13, I think.

Comment: @Nick: Oh, I see. Well I'm glad you figured it out `:)`.

Comment: Yup. Thanks for the help. I think I'm going to have 6 reputation points left after this question is finished being buried.